# How do I keep a draggable image within the rectangle boundaries of another image in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I have a chessboard image with a draggable white queen chess piece image in it and I want dragging of the piece to never exceed the boundaries of the chessboard image.

I've looked at the docs, but still can't see the way. Could someone (John Anderson) please show me how to accomplish this?

Here's the code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.behaviors import DragBehavior
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.splitter import Splitter
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.uix.image import Image

kivy.require('2.0.0')

class MoveableImage(DragBehavior, Image):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MoveableImage, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.drag_timeout = 10000000
        self.drag_distance = 0
        self.drag_rectangle = [self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height]

        self.size_hint = (.13, .13)  
        self.keep_ratio = True
        self.allow_stretch = True  

    def on_pos(self, *args):
        self.drag_rectangle = [self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height]

    def on_size(self, *args):
        self.drag_rectangle = [self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height]


class SplitBottom(Splitter):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SplitBottom, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.sizable_from = 'bottom'
        self.min_size = 200
        self.max_size = 1100 
        self.size_hint = (1, .8)  

    def on_release(self, *args):
        print('Released split1_bottom bar')
        print('Y value = %d' % self.y)


class SplitLeft(Splitter):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SplitLeft, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.sizable_from = 'left'
        self.min_size = 74
        self.max_size = 1437.2 
        self.size_hint = (3.36, 1) 

    def on_release(self, *args):
        print('Released split2_left bar')
        print('X value = %d' % self.x)


# Holds the chessboard image
class ChessboardGuiBoxlayoutVert(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ChessboardGuiBoxlayoutVert, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.orientation = 'vertical'
        self.spacing = 40
        self.chessboard_image_rect = Rectangle(size=(426.8, 426.8),
                                               pos=(0.0, 60.0))  

    def on_size(self, *args):
        print("RESIZE HAPPENED in class ChessboardGuiBoxlayoutVert")

        print('self.ids.main_image.norm_image_size = (%f, %f)' %
              (self.ids.chessboard_image.norm_image_size[0], self.ids.chessboard_image.norm_image_size[1]))

        print('Size of chessboard_image = (%f, %f)' %
              (round(self.ids.chessboard_image.norm_image_size[0], 1),
               round(self.ids.chessboard_image.norm_image_size[1], 1)))  

        # tracks position of image when resized
        print('Position of chessboard_image = (%f, %f)' %
              (round(self.ids.chessboard_image.center_x - self.ids.chessboard_image.norm_image_size[0] / 2., 1),
               round(self.ids.chessboard_image.center_y - self.ids.chessboard_image.norm_image_size[1] / 2., 1)))


class ChessBoardWidgetRelative(RelativeLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ChessBoardWidgetRelative, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.pieces_not_displayed_yet = True
        self.first_touch = True
        self.white_queen_image = None
        self.rect = Rectangle(size=(100, 100),
                              pos=(0.0, 60.0))

        self.repertoire_boxlayout_vert = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', size_hint_y=.05,
                                                   pos_hint={'center_x': .774})  

        # Padding between layout box and children: [padding_left, padding_top, padding_right, padding_bottom]
        # Padding puts space between widgets and the edge of layout holding the widgets
        # Spacing puts space between the widgets inside a layout
        self.repertoire_boxlayout_horz = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal', size_hint=(.45, None),
                                                   spacing=10, padding=[0, 55, 0, 15])

        self.white_button = Button(text='White', size_hint=(.04, 1), color=(0, 0, 0, 1),
                                   background_normal='', background_color=(128 / 255, 128 / 255, 128 / 255, 1.0),
                                   bold=True)  # grey
        self.white_button.bind(on_press=self.button_press_event_handler_for_all_buttons)
        self.black_button = Button(text='Black', size_hint=(.04, 1), color=(0, 0, 0, 1),
                                   background_normal='', background_color=(128 / 255, 128 / 255, 128 / 255, 1.0),
                                   bold=True)
        self.black_button.bind(on_press=self.button_press_event_handler_for_all_buttons)

        self.repertoire_boxlayout_horz.add_widget(Label(text='Repertoire for:', size_hint=(.08, 1)))

        self.repertoire_boxlayout_horz.add_widget(self.white_button)
        self.repertoire_boxlayout_horz.add_widget(self.black_button)

        self.repertoire_boxlayout_vert.add_widget(self.repertoire_boxlayout_horz)

        self.chessboard_gui_boxlayout_vert = ChessboardGuiBoxlayoutVert()
        print('chessboard image rect from chessboard_gui_boxlayout_vert = (%f, %f, %f, %f)' %
              (round(self.chessboard_gui_boxlayout_vert.chessboard_image_rect.pos[0], 1),
               round(self.chessboard_gui_boxlayout_vert.chessboard_image_rect.pos[1], 1),
               round(self.chessboard_gui_boxlayout_vert.chessboard_image_rect.size[0], 1),
               round(self.chessboard_gui_boxlayout_vert.chessboard_image_rect.size[1], 1)))

        self.chessboard_gui_boxlayout_vert.ids['white_button'] = self.white_button

        # default size_hint of (1,1) claims all of remaining height
        self.chessboard_image = Image(source="./data/images/chess-pieces/DarkerGreenGreyChessBoard.png", pos=self.pos,
                                      keep_ratio=True, allow_stretch=True)
        self.chessboard_gui_boxlayout_vert.ids['chessboard_image'] = self.chessboard_image

        self.chessboard_gui_boxlayout_vert.add_widget(self.chessboard_image)

        self.chessboard_gui_boxlayout_vert.add_widget(self.repertoire_boxlayout_vert)
        self.add_widget(self.chessboard_gui_boxlayout_vert)

        def update_rect(instance, value):
            instance.rect.pos = instance.pos
            instance.rect.size = instance.size
            if self.pieces_not_displayed_yet:
                test_rect = Rectangle(size=(80, 80), pos=(0.0, 58.0))  
                self.white_queen_image = MoveableImage(source="./data/images/chess-pieces/WhiteQueen57.png",
                                                       pos=test_rect.pos)
                # self.add_widget(
                #     MoveableImage(source="./data/images/chess-pieces/WhiteQueen57.png",
                #                   pos=test_rect.pos))
                self.add_widget(self.white_queen_image)

                self.pieces_not_displayed_yet = False

        self.bind(pos=update_rect, size=update_rect)

    def button_press_event_handler_for_all_buttons(self, button_instance):
        print('The button <%s> is being pressed' % button_instance.text)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):  
        print('Piece moved!!!')
        if self.first_touch:
            print('FIRST TOUCH Mouse coords = ', str(touch.pos))
            self.first_touch = False
        else:
            print('Mouse coords = ', str(touch.pos))  

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        print('ON_TOUCH_UP Mouse coords = ', str(touch.pos))

# region CURRENT LAYOUT HEIRARCHY
''' CURRENT LAYOUT HEIRARCHY
SplitterGuiBoxLayoutHorz  (root of tree)
    split1_boxlayout_vert 
        split1_bottom 
            chessboard_widget_relative
                chessboard_gui_boxlayout_vert
                    chessboard_image
                    repertoire_boxlayout_vert (supports X axis positioning of repertoire_boxlayout_horz)
                        repertoire_boxlayout_horz
                            repertoire_label
                            white_rep_button
                            black_rep_button
        s3_button
    split2 (left bar) 
        s2_button       
'''
# endregion


class SplitterGuiBoxLayoutHorz(BoxLayout):  # root
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SplitterGuiBoxLayoutHorz, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = 'horizontal'

        # Splitter 1
        split1_boxlayout_vert = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        # split1_bottom = Splitter(sizable_from='bottom', min_size=74,
        #                          max_size=1100, size_hint=(1, .8))  

        split1_bottom = SplitBottom()

        # region Create ChessBoardWidgetRelative
        chessboard_widget_relative = ChessBoardWidgetRelative()
        # endregion

        split1_bottom.add_widget(chessboard_widget_relative)
        split1_boxlayout_vert.add_widget(split1_bottom)
        s3_button = Button(text='s3', size_hint=(1, 1), background_normal='', background_color=(0, 0.1, 0.2, 1.0))
        split1_boxlayout_vert.add_widget(s3_button)
        self.add_widget(split1_boxlayout_vert)

        split2_left = SplitLeft()
        s2_button = Button(text='s2', size_hint=(.1, 1), background_normal='', background_color=(0, 0.1, 0.2, 1.0))

        split2_left.add_widget(s2_button)
        self.add_widget(split2_left)


class ChessBoxApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return SplitterGuiBoxLayoutHorz()  # root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ChessBoxApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be a complicated issue. One thing to keep in mind when dealing with `Image` widget is that the size of the picture that you see may not be the same size as the actual `Image` widget. This is especially noticeable when you use `keep_ratio: True`. So, one way to do what you want is to intercept the `on_touch_move()` method that does the dragging and adjust the `touch` event to keep the `MoveableImage` within the limits of another `Image`. Here is a modified version of your `MoveableImage` that does that:

```
class MoveableImage(DragBehavior, Image):
    limit_image = ObjectProperty(None)  # keep within this Image

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MoveableImage, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.drag_timeout = 10000000
        self.drag_distance = 0
        self.drag_rectangle = [self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height]

        self.size_hint = (.13, .13)
        self.keep_ratio = True
        self.allow_stretch = True

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if touch.grab_current is self:
            self.inside_limit_image(touch)  # keep this MoveableImage within the limit_image
        return super(MoveableImage, self).on_touch_move(touch)

    def inside_limit_image(self, touch):
        if self.limit_image is None:
            return

        # calculate limits of actual picture inside this MoveableImage
        m_image_min_x = self.x + (self.width - self.norm_image_size[0])/2.
        m_image_min_y = self.y + (self.height - self.norm_image_size[1])/2.
        m_image_max_x = m_image_min_x + self.norm_image_size[0]
        m_image_max_y = m_image_min_y + self.norm_image_size[1]

        # calculate where limits of picture in the MoveableImage would be if move is allowed
        new_min = [m_image_min_x + touch.dx, m_image_min_y + touch.dy]
        new_max = [new_min[0] + self.norm_image_size[0], new_min[1] + self.norm_image_size[1]]

        # calculate limits of picture in the limit_image
        image_min_x = self.limit_image.x + (self.limit_image.width - self.limit_image.norm_image_size[0]) / 2.
        image_min_y = self.limit_image.y + (self.limit_image.height - self.limit_image.norm_image_size[1]) / 2.
        image_max_x = image_min_x + self.limit_image.norm_image_size[0]
        image_max_y = image_min_y + self.limit_image.norm_image_size[1]

        # adjust touch, if necessary, to keep MoveableImage within limit_image
        if new_min[0] < image_min_x:
            touch.dx = image_min_x - m_image_min_x
        if new_min[1] < image_min_y:
            touch.dy = image_min_y - m_image_min_y
        if new_max[0] > image_max_x:
            touch.dx = image_max_x - m_image_max_x
        if new_max[1] > image_max_y:
            touch.dy = image_max_y - m_image_max_y
        return

    def on_pos(self, *args):
        self.drag_rectangle = [self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height]

    def on_size(self, *args):
        self.drag_rectangle = [self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height]
```

Now, when you use this `MoveableImage`, you should provide a reference to the  `limit_image`, like this:

```
self.white_queen_image = MoveableImage(source="/data/images/chess-pieces/WhiteQueen57.png", limit_image=self.chessboard_image, pos=test_rect.pos)
```

Comment: WOW!!! Thank you John Anderson! This was far more involved than I realized since Kivy is quite new for me. You are truly some super-expert in Kivy!